# 2 WAY ANOVA if groups are missing

Tags: anova, missing-data

I like to set up a 2 way repeated measures anova. I compare 4 models with 4 ages and see if the results differ, this should result in around 16 groups, since 4*4=16 (so far so good)

However from some groups I don't have the data so I still have 2 factors to test for but not longer 16 groups but 15-14.

This is not due to mistakes but due to the fact that the groups under this condition are just bad and don't meet standard recommondations.

If however I'll try to do 2 way repeated measurments including my missing groups, I can't execute it.

Is there a way to handle this missing groups?

Greetings